# MSSQL inserts strings with random spaces inside words to table

Tags: c#, database, string

I have an ASP support application that gets a string from the user and inserts it into the table, making a new record. The field is VARCHAR(4000) in case there are long sql commands or code snippets to record. The problem is, MSSQL puts random spaces in these strings. In the string I see \r\n characters whilst debugging the program but no spaces within random words, like i see in the database. I must eliminate these spaces in the insert and also, read the strings from database with the correct spaces and newlines. Here is my code. The string is the "detay" field. The code seems fine, is the problem in MSSQL or my sql statement? The variables are half turkish, ask in case you need a translation so i will edit.

```
  protected void btnkaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtbaslik.Text == "")
        {
            baslikErr.Text = "ERROR";
            baslikErr.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            baslikErr.Visible = false;
        }
        if (txtdetay.Text == "")
        {
            detayErr.Text = "ERROR";
            detayErr.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            detayErr.Visible = false;
        }
        if (txtdetay.Text != "" && txtbaslik.Text != "")
        {
            OdbcConnection baglanti = new OdbcConnection();
            StringBuilder sorgu = new StringBuilder();
            OdbcCommand komut = new OdbcCommand();

            string veritabani = null;
            veritabani = ;//cant give the db string for reasons :)
            baglanti.ConnectionString = veritabani;
            baglanti.Open();
            veritabani = null;

            komut = baglanti.CreateCommand();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnFilename.Value))
            {
                sorgu.Append(" INSERT INTO DESTEK (baslik, detay, tarih) VALUES (?,?,?) ");
                komut.CommandText = sorgu.ToString();

                komut.Parameters.Add("@baslik", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = this.txtbaslik.Text;
                komut.Parameters.Add("@detay", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = this.txtdetay.Text;
                komut.Parameters.Add("@tarih", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                sorgu.Append(" INSERT INTO DESTEK (baslik, detay, tarih, dosya) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ");
                komut.CommandText = sorgu.ToString();

                komut.Parameters.Add("@baslik", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = this.txtbaslik.Text;
                komut.Parameters.Add("@detay", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = this.txtdetay.Text;
                komut.Parameters.Add("@tarih", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                komut.Parameters.Add("@dosya", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = hdnFilename.Value;
            }
            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();

            komut = null;

            baglanti.Close();
            baglanti = null;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you use `OdbcType.NVarChar`?

Comment: You can answer your own question you know? You shouldn't put answers in questions also

Comment: yeah, didnt know that thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my answer.

```
        string detay = this.txtdetay.Text;
        detay = detay.Replace(@"\r\n", "");
        detay = detay.Replace((char)13, '£');
        detay = detay.Replace((char)10, '£');
        detay = detay.Replace("£", "");
```

Apparently i had to replace the escape characters with spaces. Leaving this here, in case anyone else has same issue.